# How to set up a new instance of View.IOntouchListener in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, ontouchlistener

I have something like this

```
private void setTouchUpListener(final Canvas c, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final float dX, final float dY, final int actionState, final boolean isCurrentlyActive)
{
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
 @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
   {
```

How would i be able to do this in Xamarin Android,im new to xamarin and C#,because i need to use the methods elements like canvas and other stuff

Comment: There is no anonymous inner class in C#, @MilanG's answer is what we  usually do in Xamarin.Android.  By`some things that were defined outside the MyTouch class`, can you explain it?

Comment: I have a set of variable which i need to access

Comment: I assume the variables are in your Activity, if so, you can pass the `Context` to `MyTouchListener` class, and then you can access the variables by `Context`.

Comment: Yea,i figured,but kinda sucks :|

Comment: You can use c# delegate, I think it will help you. You just need create some method in you Activity to operate the variables and call the delegate in `MyTouchListener` class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `View.IOnTouchListener` interface on a class like:

```
public class MyTouchListener : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnTouchListener
{
    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
        {
            // do your stuff here
            return true;
        }
        if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
        {
            // do your stuff here
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this like:

```
recyclerView.SetOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
```

Comment: I saw this example,but i'm not sure how this would help my case,i'm new to c#

Comment: You can implement this interface directly to the class/activity where your recyclerView lies. It is not always necessary to create a new class for this. Ex. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-a-touch-event-in-xamarin-android-app-using-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: Its not that,i want to use some things that were defined outside the MyTouch class,this sucks so much

Comment: If you can describe the relation among calling/called methods/objects via some code snippets (describing your case) then it would be helpful to identify where you should implement this interface, in your case.